# What does it mean when the values of direction range from -11 to >360?

Tags: angle

I have a data file containing the direction of energy flux ranging from -0.192 to 6.335. I thought this was just the direction in radians and converted to degrees to find the values ranging from -11 to 363. Does this mean I just have to add/subtract 360 to get the actual values or is something wrong with the data? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the meaning of the data is as you describe (which I don't know beyond your assurance of such) then yes, you can map all of the values back to a single half-open interval around the circle, say $[0^{\circ}, 360^{\circ})$, by adding (or subtracting) the integer multiple of $360^{\circ}$ that will put each point into that interval.

This will make your data "well-behaved" in that the same direction won't have multiple values of the angle.

Now, if you only need to calculate some quantity based on the direction then it's not really necessary to do anything to the data.  The sine of $3^{\circ}$ is the same as the sine of $363^{\circ}$.